# Why the host part of a Mask is 254 (256-2) instead of 253?

Tags: ip

Don't hate me for being such a newbie but I'm so confused. If we have 32 bits, each octet adds up to 255, why the host part is 254 (in a 255.255.255.0 mask) instead of 255 - 2 ?

Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I deeply value it, I know it's surely a very dumb question since I couldn't find it elsewehere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but if you ask "why can we have 254 hosts in a /24 network" then:

the all zero is also an address, so while it add ups to 255 as you said, it doesn't start from 1 but from 0.

so you have 0 -> 255 = 256 addresses.

2 of those addresses are reserved, for the network address and the broadcast address. This is why we end up with 254 addresses available for the hosts.

One of this host is the gateway (router) and so, we could also say we have 253 addresses available for end devices.

Comment: Thanks so so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I completely understand it and i feel quite dumb now lol. I would upvote every reply but the forum doesn't allow me yet. You guys are awesome, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Because you have 256 different values: 0 to 255. The same thing for the number of decimal digits. There are 10 digits (base 10) but they are 0 to 9.

Since you have 256 different values in an octet (0 to 255), and you subtract two (network and broadcast) you have 254 valid host addresses for a `/24` network (1 to 254).

Comment: Thanks so so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I completely understand it and i feel quite dumb now lol. I would upvote every reply but the forum doesn't allow me yet. You guys are awesome, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Decimal `255` is `1111 1111` in binary. Since the host part in an IPv4 address must not be all `1`s  (that address is used for the subnet's *directed broadcast address*), addresses like that cannot be used for a host. A host part with binary `10` at the end like `254` has no special meaning and is usable.

Note that this restriction doesn't only apply for addresses ending in `.255` but depend on the currently used subnet mask. For instance, on the `10.0.0.8/30` subnet, the directed broadcast address that cannot be used as host address is `10.0.0.11`.

A host part with all `0`s isn't usuable either (that address is identical to the subnet prefix), so that leaves you with 254 usable host addresses for a /24 subnet (2<sup>(32-24)</sup>-2), including any gateways.

The only exception to those rules is with `/31` point-to-point subnets where both addresses are explicitly usable for hosts and there is no directed broadcast. In that case, an IP address ending in `.255` may be a perfectly valid host address.

Comment: Thanks so so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I completely understand it and i feel quite dumb now lol. I would upvote every reply but the forum doesn't allow me yet. You guys are awesome, thanks again!